# Facebook C# SDk user registration

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to implement user registration on my mvc3 site using fb. My question is regard this bit of code

```
    FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    dynamic me = fbClient.Get("me?fields=id,name");
```

What other parameters can be specified in the request "me?fields=id,name,??". My application requires Email Address, phone number, address and name (first name, last name). I would be grateful if someone could tell me or better yet point to to somewhere I can find documentation on this.

Comment: Ha, I found it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sample of the parameters you get inside **dynamic me = fb.Get("me")** without user permission:

"**id**":"894555532"
"**name**":"John Doe"
"**first_name**":"John"
"**last_name**":"Doe"
"**link**":"http://www.facebook.com/johndoe"
"**username**":"john"
"**bio**":"Sample bio"
"**quotes**":"\"Sample quote""
"**work**":[{"**employer**":{"**id**":"39233323343","**name**":"Sample Company"}
"**position**":{"**id**":"142461033332450","**name**":"Backend Developer"}
"**projects**":[{"**id**":"214103971985333"
"**name**":"Coors Light, Sample Project"}]}]
"**favorite_teams**":[{"**id**":"171522852874952","**name**":"Juventus"},{"**id**":"112325268793829","**name**":"Barcelona F.C."}]
"**favorite_athletes**":[{"**id**":"326971266226","**name**":"Alessandro Del Piero"}]
"**gender**":"male"
"**timezone**":-6
"**locale**":"en_US"
"**verified**":true
"**updated_time**""2012-01-24T09:12:17+0000"}

"**email**" requires user permission

I'm sure there are other things you can get, though there is no official list for c# sdk yet.

### This is a sample of how to get all that info:

```cs
var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic me = fb.Get("me");

imgProfilePic.ImageUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", me.id);
lblName.Text = me.name;
lblFirstName.Text = me.first_name;
lblLastName.Text = me.last_name;
```

### Here's an updated / complete list a scopes for Facebook C# SDK:

```
ads_management
create_event 
create_note 
email 
export_stream 
friends_about_me 
friends_activities 
friends_birthday 
friends_checkins 
friends_education_history 
friends_events 
friends_games_activity 
friends_groups 
friends_hometown 
friends_interests 
friends_likes 
friends_location 
friends_location_posts 
friends_notes 
friends_online_presence 
friends_photo_video_tags 
friends_photos 
friends_questions 
friends_relationship_details 
friends_relationships 
friends_religion_politics 
friends_status 
friends_subscriptions 
friends_videos 
friends_website 
friends_work_history 
manage_friendlists 
manage_notifications 
manage_pages 
offline_access 
photo_upload 
publish_actions 
publish_checkins 
publish_stream 
read_friendlists 
read_insights 
read_mailbox 
read_requests 
read_stream 
rsvp_event 
share_item 
sms 
status_update 
user_about_me 
user_activities 
user_birthday 
user_checkins 
user_education_history 
user_events 
user_games_activity 
user_groups 
user_hometown 
user_interests 
user_likes 
user_location 
user_location_posts 
user_notes 
user_online_presence 
user_photo_video_tags 
user_photos 
user_questions 
user_relationship_details 
user_relationships 
user_religion_politics 
user_status 
user_subscriptions 
user_videos 
user_website 
user_work_history 
video_upload xmpp_login
```